# Unity and Vuforia: draw object trails

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm looking for a solution to draw Unity3D trails (using Trail Renderer) when moving the object with Vuforia marker.

Let's say I have a box on top of the marker and whenever I move my marker I'd like my box's trail to follow the object (curved line). So far, my trail is a straight line, most probably because trail attached to the box object calculates object's local coordinate system.

Any ideas how to solve this? If this isn't doable with Vuforia+Unity, any ideas where to search for a better combination?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that in Vuforia the GameObjects attached to the markers are not moving at all, instead of that, is the camera who's moving arround the GameObject.

Start checking that, probably it's the reason why you are not getting the trails working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Vancete. You were right. I should change World Center Mode from "First Target" to "Specific Target"